# gcc compiler can't find include file stdio.h

Tags: compiling, gcc, c

The `gcc` compiler can't find the include file `stdio.h`.

```
$ batcat test.c
───────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: test.c
───────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ #include <stdio.h>
   2   │ int main(void){
   3   │     printf("hello world");
   4   │     return 0;
   5   │ }

$ gcc test.c
In file included from test.c:1:
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:6:10: fatal error: sys/stdio.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <sys/stdio.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

as you can see below, the `stdio.h` file is present in the `/usr/local/include` directory.

```
/usr/local/include  via  v11.3.0-gcc
$ ls
assert.h  float.h     locale.h  stdarg.h   stdio.h   wchar.h
bits      inttypes.h  math.h    stdbool.h  stdlib.h  wctype.h
ctype.h   iso646.h    setjmp.h  stddef.h   string.h
errno.h   limits.h    signal.h  stdint.h   time.h
```

I have tried reinstalling `gcc`, `libc6`, `libc6-dev` as well.

Comment: Packages from the Ubuntu repositories normally don't install files in /usr/local - normally, gcc would resolve `#include <stdio.h>` as `/usr/include/stdio.h` for example. Have you manually installed standard library files to /usr/local?

Comment: I'm not a developer nor specially knowledgeable about gcc, but I do believe that installation of complex software (e.g. gcc) is best done via 'standard means'. For ubuntu that is starting with `sudo apt install build-essentials` and then possibly by adding other *.deb packages from the same or related repositories. Ubuntu 20.04 has gcc 9.4, later releases might have newer versions, but most likely still with stdio.h placed in /usr/include/stdio.h - so the impression is that you have used some other means to get your gcc installed, and failed to get it done correctly.

Comment: @Hannu even if gcc is correctly installed from the Ubuntu repo, it will search /usr/local/include before /usr/include I think (you can display the built-in search paths with `: | gcc -v -E -xc -` for example)

Comment: @steeldriver you were right. include files should not be in /usr/local for gcc. I was trying to install another compiler which messed up the gcc. rm -rf /usr/local/include helped in resolving it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> The reason that triggered this problem was installing an alternative compiler called scc from source. It seems that this somehow conflicted with runtime paths for `gcc`.
>
> My initial impression from the discussions in the comments was that the include files for `gcc` should not be in `/usr/local/include` directory but the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/cpp/Search-Path.html) does say that `gcc` checks this directory for include files. So I'm not sure what was the problem.
>
> I deleted this folder entirely and that resolved the issue for me:
>
> ```
> rm -rf /usr/local/include/
> ```

<sup>Answer moved here from [OP's question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1451241/3).</sup>